# Why the time complexity of insertion in a redis SET is O(n)?

Tags: data-structures, redis, set

I was reading the redis's help page for SADD command. http://redis.io/commands/sadd

Then I found a comment where someone is asking the following

> I am wondering how this operation complexity can be O(N) for N members
>   added ? How is performed the unicity check ? Does redis store a hash
>   table with all members of all SETs ?

Turns out it is a good question and I'm very curious about why insertion is O(n) with SETs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Complexity is not O(n) but O(N) for N members added. Concretely, it means that you can consider that each insertion operation is done in constant time - O(1) - which is only asymptotically true.

Hereunder, we suppose that n is the number of items in the set.

To perform a SADD operation Redis has to first lookup the object representing the set (hash lookup - complexity O(1)), and then try to add the item in the object itself.

The set can be represented in memory as an intset or a hash table.

If the object is a intset (i.e. a sorted vector of integers), it will perform a binary search to search for the position of the item - O(log n) and then eventually, insert the item - O(n) - however this is only for small values of n. The set-max-intset-entries must be chosen so that the whole object fits in the CPU caches for optimal performance.

If the object is a hash table, then Redis will have to perform a lookup and add the item if needed - complexity is O(1).

Because a SADD command can add N items, the resulting asymptotic complexity is O(N).

Answer (score -2):

Inspired From [the reference](https://redis.io/commands/sadd#:~:text=Time%20complexity,multiple%20arguments.):

`SADD` command Time complexity is **O(1)** when you pass only 1 value to add in the SET.

So the below command's complexity is O(1):

```
SADD my_set_name "a_new_value"
```

And O(N) for when you pass multiple value to the `SADD` command(N = number of passed parameters).

So the below command's complexity is O(3)

```
SADD my_set_name "a_new_value" "another_new_value" "another_new_value"
```

Read more [here](https://redis.io/commands/sadd#:~:text=Time%20complexity,multiple%20arguments.).

Comment: It's the best algorithm you will ever see for add a new element to a unique list of random strings.